# Y a des baffs qui se perdent

Tags: sens

Je n’ai pas vraiment compris la dernière phrase dans [cette video](https://www.instagram.com/reel/CP3ea74I-FO/?utm_medium=copy_link) de Tibo.

> Y a des baffs qui se perdent.

C’est bien ça qu’il dit ou je me trompe ?

Qu’est-ce que ça veut dire ? Merci !

Comment: Généralement, on écrit "baffes" (=Gifles, coups).

Comment: ...à moins que le vidéo ne parle des popcorns au caramel

Comment: @vc74 Les fameux popcorns dont on voyait les publicités au cinéma à coté de Jean mineur (médiavison)!

Comment: @XouDo Ceux-là même, oui :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oui, c'est bien ce qui est dit dans la vidéo; l'orthographe correcte de « baff » est « baffe ».

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baffe)) Pop. Gifle. Flanquer, envoyer une baffe

- *Il y a des gifle/claques/baffes qui se perdent.*      Cela, dit  dans une situation donnée, signifie  que certains individus ont dans cette situation un comportement qui est tellement dans l'erreur, tellement contraire au bon sens, qu'on peut penser qu'ils méritent une punition exemplaire, extrême, telle que celle de recevoir des gifles ; mais comme ce type de comportement qui consiste à gifler des gens n'est pas du tout acceptable et que des gifles ne sont en fait pas données dans de telles circonstances, on dit que les gifles sont perdues, en quelque sorte on dit  qu'il y a eu un gaspillage de moyens qui auraient pu être utilisés à bon escient, mais cela n'est que jeu d'esprit et il n'y a pas de réalité dans les mots pris au pied de la lettre.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/il_y_a_des_claques_qui_se_perdent)) l y a des claques qui se perdent \il j‿a de klak ki sə pɛʁd\
> (Figuré) Une ou plusieurs personnes qui ont un comportement ou tiennent des propos insupportables en toute impunité mériteraient d’être vertement remises à leur place.

L'utilisation de cette formule toute faite n'est pas recommendable ; l'idée  est perçue comme assez rude ; c'est pourquoi cet adage populaire est à bannir  de toute discussion sérieuse dans laquelle il est question de légalité, de problèmes psychologiques, de morale, de mœurs… et cela, quel que soit celui des trois mots possibles (gifle/claques/baffes)  qui est utilisé.